# Shortcut target field, window size

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, shortcuts

I have a game that I have set to startup in windowed mode, however I would like to know if there is a way to define the window size, here is an example of the target field:

```
C:/program files/game/game.exe -w
```

This part works just fine, I want to know if there is a way to say something like `-1280x760`
to define the window size.

Answer (score 7):

The conceptual misconception you have here is that you assume that command line options are generic or common across all programs.

They aren't.

For instance, I could write a program that shuts down the system when passing a command line argument such as `-w`, or `-1280x760`. I could write a program that deletes all files on your computer and sends a command to launch a missile in response to receiving **any** command line argument.

Command line arguments are **application-specific**, **arbitrary** commands that are *completely* dependent on the behavior of the individual program. So, where one game might treat `-w` as "run in windowed mode", another game might treat it as "make it impossible to ever win the game again, and deactivate my multiplayer account".

Since you said "game" (in the generic) instead of telling us **what** game you are playing in particular, we can not help you any further.

Comment: The game I am trying to play is diablo 2

Comment: [Let me google that for you](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=diablo+2+set+window+size+command+line). First result: [here](http://diablo2.diablowiki.net/Game_commands). Scroll down a bit. 
-res800 start window in 800x600
-res640 start window in 640x480

Comment: I was hoping there would be more options than just the 2 resolutions, but thank you for the help

Comment: You can try -res1280 or -res1024 but if it doesn't do anything, then probably nothing else is supported. Can't you set the resolution manually in the game settings?

Comment: Unfortunately not, with more research I found that the game only supports 800x600 as max resolution, thats what happens I guess when you try to play a game that's 13 years old

Comment: The game engine would have to be open-sourced so that a programmer could go in and increase resolution support to something higher, that is the only way I can think of that would raise the maximum resolution beyond 800x600. So you should probably settle with what you have.