# What are target command line options in windows?

Tags: windows

I have .exe file. In the `target` field of the properties, I have:

> [ "C:/..path/file1.exe" -wr"D:\path2\folder" -wuName -wiName -wpName].

I want to know if there is some kind of list of command options to the `target` field.

Comment: Options for _what_ target of _what_?

Comment: i have .exe file. In the target field, I have:[
"C:/..path/file1.exe" -wr"D:\path2\folder" -wuName -wiName -wpName]
I'm just trying to understand where can I find those options?

Comment: If none of the answers below work for you, try googling `"file1.exe"` and/or one or more of the names of its options, like `-wr`, `-wu`, and `-wp`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shortcut target field, window size](http://superuser.com/questions/589914/shortcut-target-field-window-size)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each program / executable can have its own parameters. In general, you can find out what parameters a program expects by

1. opening a command prompt
2. typing `program.exe /?` or `program.exe -help` or `program.exe --help`

Even the way the parameters are passed aren't equal, some programs expect a `/`, some a `-` ...

Comment: thanks much! that helped a lot! and thanks to those who helped as well!

Answer (score 0):

From the command prompt, type `help`. This will provide a list of options available. If you then want to know the specific options for each, type `help example` or `example /?`, where `example` is one of the options from the original list.

A full list of them is also [available online](http://ss64.com/nt/), but I can't vouch for accuracy. (although at a glance it seems sound.)